# Matlab Reading List of List from a Text File as String

Tags: string, file, matlab, vector

I am a Java developer and new to Matlab. I have a file something like that:

```
Label_X sdfasf sadfl  asdf a fasdlkjf asd 
Label_Y lmdfgl ldfkgldkj dkljdkljdlkjdklj
Label_X sfdsa sdfsafasfsafasf 234|3#ert 44
Label_X sdfsfdsf____asdfsadf _ dsfsd
Label_Y !^dfskşfsşk o o  o o 4545
```

What I want is:

A vector (array) includes labels:

```
Label Array:
Label_X
Label_Y
Label_X
Label_X
Label_Y
```

and a List (has five elements for our example) and every element of list has elements size of delimited strings. I mean

```
Element Number   Value(List of strings)                Element size of value list
--------------   ----------------------                --------------------------
1                sdfasf,sadfl,asdf,a,fasdlkjf,asd      6 
2                lmdfgl,ldfkgldkj,dkljdkljdlkjdklj     3
3                sfdsa,sdfsafasfsafasf,234|3#ert,44    4
4                sdfsfdsf____asdfsadf,_,dsfsd          3
5                !^dfskşfsşk,o,o,o,o,4545              6
```

I know it is pretty simple with Java but I don't know how to implement it in Matlab.

**PS:** What I am doing is that. I have a text file includes tweets of people. First word is label at row, and other words are corresponding words related to that label. I will have a list of labels and another list of list that holds words about each label.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't optimal, but it should do the trick

```
all = textread('test.txt', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n','whitespace', '');
List = cell(size(all));
for i = 1:size(all)
    [List{i}.name remain]    = strtok(all{i}, ' ');
    [List{i}.content remain] = strtok(remain, ' ');
    j = 0;
    while(size(remain,2)>0)
        j = j+1;
        List{i}.content = [List{i}.content temp ','];
        [temp remain] = strtok(remain, ' ');
    end
    List{i}.size = j;
end
```

Comment: It gives error at here: List{i}.content = [List{i}.content temp ','];

Answer (score 0):

The best construct for this in Matlab is the cell. Cells can contain one object, of any type, and are typically found in arrays themselves. Something like this should work, and be pretty optimal (Assuming you don't expect more than 10K lines);

```
output=cell(10000,1);     %This should be set to the maximum number of lines you ever expect to have
output_names=cell(size(output));
output_used=false(size(output));
fid=fopen('filename.txt','r');
index=0;
while ~feof(fid)
   index=index+1;
   line=fgets(fid);
   splited_names=regexp(line,'\w*','split');
   output{index}=splited_names(2:end);
   output_names{index}=splited_names(1);
   output_used(index)=true;
end
output=output(output_used);
output_names=output_names(output_used);
```